# Why do colliding blocks compute to $\pi$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, elasticity, integrable-systems

If you take two blocks on a frictionless plane (each block is 1kg) with one wall and perfectly elastic collisions, if you collided the block on the right with the one on the left (wall is on the left) there would be 3 collisions. if we replaced the block on the right with a 100 kg block, there would be 31 collisions. If we replaced the right one yet again with a 10,000 kg block, there would be 314 collisions. As long as you multiply the right blocks kg by powers of 100, the total number of collisions will always be the starting digits of pi. My question is, why is this so?

Comment: 3blue1brown has a video on this - [Why do colliding blocks compute pi?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsYwFizhncE)

Comment: Please refer to 3blue1brown in YouTube which has an amazing video explaining this intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

The original paper about this phenomenon is [Playing pool with $\pi$](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Elebed/Galperin.%20Playing%20pool%20with%20pi.pdf) by G. Galperin (2003); as other commentators have noted it was animated and explained *excellently* in a series of youtube videos by 3Blue1Brown ([first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs), [second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsYwFizhncE&t=0s), [third](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brU5yLm9DZM&t=0s)).

The proof in Galperin is quite readable, and the video explains it well, but here is the gist of what is going on:

[image]

(1) The state of the system can be described by the positions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ of the small and big masses, with $x(t)<y(t)$. As they move the point $(x(t),y(t))$ move in a straight line except when they collide (at $x=y$) or there is a bounce from the wall $(x=0)$.

(2) This can be turned into [a billiard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards) inside a triangular open wedge by vertically rescaling the x-coordinate by $\sqrt{m}$ and the y-coordinate by $\sqrt{M}$, making the bounces behave like proper billiard bounces with equal incoming and outgoing angles. The wedge has an opening angle $\alpha=\arctan(m/M)$ set by the ratio of the masses. In this problem $M=m 10^N$ so $\alpha=\arctan(10^{-N})$.

[image]

(3) Like many billiard or reflection problems it can be solved by placing reflected copies of the wedge behind the "mirror" of its walls, and letting the trajectory continue inside these extra domains. The number of bounces corresponds to the number of times it crosses the domain walls. This will be $$\Pi = \left\lfloor \frac{\pi}{\arctan(10^{-N})}\right\rfloor.$$

(4) The final part is to show that $\arctan(10^{-N})$ quickly becomes close to $10^{-N}$, making $\Pi$ a $N$ digit integer approximation to $\pi$.

It is a quite remarkable result, and hinges on several not entirely trivial details.